# How do i get Route 53 to point to example.com/page?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

It's fairly straightforward to get Route 53 to get users to go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Instead of my EC2 public address 34.556.24.23 etc....

However i have my `example.com` as my Wordpress landing page, and i would like my actual app that's running on my EC2 instance at 34.556.24.23 etc...., to be found at `www.example.com/demo`

It's not a subdomain, its a path.

How do I go about pointing to that?

Comment: DNS knows nothing about HTTP and paths. The typical solution is to use HTTP redirects that you configure at your server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

DNS works by resolving a DNS name (domain name) into an IP address.

It is not possible to include a path in a DNS name.

However, you might be able to use [Forward a Domain – WordPress.com Support](https://wordpress.com/support/domains/domain-forwarding/) to instruct WordPress to redirect users based upon the domain that was used to access the site.